# How to scroll ImageView horizontal in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-scroll

In my application I want show image from server into `ImageView`.
My `imageView` **fill the all of screen** and for this I use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` .

But when use `centerCrop` not show all of the image detail?

I want horizontal scroll on `imageView` **automatically** (with normal speed) of by **user finger**.

**My XML code :**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wallpaperDetail_img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="patch_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

**My Full XML code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.Wallpapers.WallpaperDetailActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/wallpaperDetail_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_simple" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/wallpaperDetail_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wallpaperDetail_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/wallpaperDetail_loader"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size25"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size25"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <io.github.yavski.fabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial
        android:id="@+id/wallpaperDetail_fabMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:fabGravity="bottom_end"
        app:fabMenu="@menu/menu_wallpaper_detail"
        app:miniFabBackgroundTintList="@array/fab_menu_item_colors"
        app:fabBackgroundTint="@color/catMenuColor2"
        app:miniFabDrawableTint="@android:color/white"
        app:miniFabTitleTextColorList="@array/fab_menu_item_colors"
        app:touchGuardDrawable="@drawable/background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My java code for get image from server :**

```
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .asBitmap()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(wallpaperDetail_img);
```

How can I **horizontal scroll** on `ImageView`? How can I it?

Comment: Than Load your image in `WebView`

Comment: @NileshRathod, can you send to me for set image Into WebView java code? please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037260/load-image-from-url-in-webview-center-vertically and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764224/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod, thanks but I want use imageView! can you send to me library or code?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HorizontalScrollView`:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wallpaperDetail_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want fill all of screen, use centerCrop, no matrix. can you help me?

Comment: Use centerCrop. What is the problem?

Comment: When use centerCrop no scrolling. but when use matrix I can scroll on ImageView

Comment: Yes you can, if there is something to scroll to. I'm doing it right now.

Comment: Copy and paste the above code, change the name of the drawable and test it

Comment: Did you change the ImageView to  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and      `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`?

Comment: I remove my code and replace your code. but not work me again

Comment: Post the full xml as it is now

Comment: I can't reproduce your xml since you have 3d party widgets. Last try change the HorizontalScrollView's height and width to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
        horizontalScrollView (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontal_grid);
    int[] images = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, 
     ....R.drawable.image10};
    LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.horizontal_container);
    for (int i=0 ; i<images.length; i++){
        ImageView iv = new ImageView (this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        iv.setPadding(4,0,0,0);
        iv.setImageResource(images[i]);
        iv.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
        sv.addView(iv);
    }
```

And your xml should look something like this

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="40">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```